# How to access routeProps (history, match, location) from a route-rendered component using react-router-dom in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to work with `react-router-dom` and Typescript.

I have installed `@types/react-router-dom`.

But I'm having trouble finding the `routeProps`: `history`, `match` and `location` in my rendered components.

I mean, I know they are present, but Typescript is not aware of them.

[image]

[image]

This is how I'm rendering this route:

[image]

I saw [here](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/react-router-typescript) and [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-typescript-example?file=package.json) that you are supposed to install `@types/react-router`. Is this correct? Could this be the reason that I'm not seeing the `routeProps` in my route-rendered components?

**UPDATE:**

I've installed `@types/react-router` but still can't access those props from the rendered component.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to access the `routeProps` (`history`, `match` and `location`) inside the `<Route/>` rendered component:

```
import React from "react";
import HomePage from "./HomePage";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";

// NEEDS TO EXTEND YOUR PROPS TO ADD RouteComponentProps from @types/react-router-dom

interface HomeContainer extends RouteComponentProps {
}

const HomeContainer: React.FC<HomeContainer> = (props) => {
  console.log("Rendering HomeContainer...");

  props.

  return(
    <HomePage/>
  );
};

export default HomeContainer;
```

Now `history`, `match` and `location` are accessible from the `props` object.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. The interface and the component should have different names
2. In the component it is necessary to describe the type of the received props